# How do I adjust the ImageView in ListView?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-listview, imageview

How can I move the `ImageView` to left hand-side like image below ?

[image]

This is my listView and the layout.

[image]

**custom_row.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/ListType"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@color/black"/>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/ListAmount"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textColor="@color/blue"/>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/ListDescription"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textColor="@color/blue"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:id="@+id/photo" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, give it a try to use `LinearLayout` as in code below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/photo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ListType"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ListAmount"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/blue"
            android:textSize="17sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ListDescription"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/blue"
            android:textSize="17sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please, try to use `RelativeLayout` instead  of `LinearLayout`. Why? Here I would give you some reasons:

1. It would be much easier to align anything anywhere on given layout.
2. You can define the attributes for aligning and arranging easily.
3. You can drag in the views and arrange them in `Android Studio`.

Answer (score 1):

Easier to use Relative Layout here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <!-- Sit image to the Parent's left -->
    <ImageView
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:id="@+id/photo" />

   <!-- Position, to right of Image & Stack views relative here as well -->
   <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/photo"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">
        <TextView android:id="@+id/ListType"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/ListAmount"
            android:layout_below="@+id/listType"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:textColor="@color/blue"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/ListDescription"
            android:layout_below="@+id/ListAmount"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:textColor="@color/blue"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your desired layout required the Nested Layout strategy.

Your top linear layout should have `horizontal` orientation inside it there are two child layout, one is `imageview` and another is `LinearLayout`.
Second Linear layout has `vertical` orientation in which you can add more child view such as in your case amount, claim type etc.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="25dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:id="@+id/photo" />
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
 <TextView android:id="@+id/ListType"
      android:textSize="17sp"
      android:textStyle="bold"
      android:textColor="@color/black"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
  <TextView android:id="@+id/ListAmount"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:textSize="17sp"
      android:textColor="@color/blue"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
  <TextView android:id="@+id/ListDescription"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:textSize="17sp"
      android:textColor="@color/blue"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

 </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

You can get more idea about complex layout : [here](http://www.learn-android-easily.com/2013/05/nested-linear-layout-in-android.html)

You should learn about different layout type for different purpose.
In the above snippet you may use layout_weight to give view a fixed wieht/area in its parent layout

Answer (score 1):

please find the code below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:id="@+id/photo"
                android:layout_weight=".2"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.8">
                <TextView android:id="@+id/ListType"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="17sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"/>

                <TextView android:id="@+id/ListAmount"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="17sp"
                    android:textColor="@color/blue"/>

                <TextView android:id="@+id/ListDescription"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="17sp"
                    android:textColor="@color/blue"/>
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

[image: Please find screenshot below]

Comment: does your problem soled? I would appreciate if you accept my answer if it helps